# Decentralized / Distributed Private Key Generation between Untrusted Parties?

Tags: public-key, key-exchange, multiparty-computation, key-distribution, distributed-decryption

I found an interesting concept in this paper, **page 13**, ([Link to the paper](https://enigma.co/enigma_full.pdf)) called "**Decentralized private key generation**", as follows:

> "Decentralized private key generation – Multiple Enigma nodes locally
>   create a segment of the key, whereas the full key is only ever
>   assembled by the user. No trail of evidence is left anywhere."

I want to implement such an approach and I need to know the process step by step.

Assuming:

1. We have `n` **untrusted parties** in a network.
2. Parties are identified only their public keys.
3. The target is to generate a single new private key across these parties.
4. Only one of these parties eventually can access to this private key. We call this party as "winner".
5. This winner party will be selected by a random process.
6. This winner party will be selected as a "voter", such that any party holding that private key will be able to vote using this private key and the rest parties will accept this vote.
7. So, verifying this vote is crucial and the rest of parties will be only related public key of that private key.

Is this process possible using a **distributed private key generation** ? And if yes, what is the steps?

*If you need any more detailed information about the scenario, please let me know.*

Comment: Have you tried doing a literature search for distributed key generation?

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage , Yes, I found several results. I am not sure if there is a more appropriate approach for particular example that I explained in my question? Or all of them are the same ? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Can you formulate it as a specific question about a specific distributed key generation protocol?

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage , I try to explain my example in more details.

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage , I edited my question. Thank you